# ADB pm grant not working for some permissions on Android 10

Tags: android, adb, android-10.0

I'm trying the new android 10 and checking its differences with previous versions. I tried to grant some permissions through `ADB` that used to work on Android 9 but to no avail.

Since it is ADB related, I'm not sure where to check it documentation, but here is what I tried:

```
pm grant my.package.app android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION // permission granted
pm grant my.package.app android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE // no error no permission granted
pm grant my.package.app android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO // no error no permission granted
pm grant my.package.app android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE // no error no permission granted
pm revoke my.package.app android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE // permission revoked
pm revoke my.package.app android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS // permission revoked
```

Those are all permissions declared in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, it is strange that only the new `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` worked but none of the existing permissions did.
I believe the permission's names are correct because it works when revoking it.

Alternatively, I tried to find the string for those permissions and use the `appops` command but it didn't work either.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT:

After further investigation, I noticed that when an app is **Freshly** installed then I use `pm grant` every thing works as expected. However after denying the permission manually (from settings) `pm grant` is not working anymore

Comment: you should put your EDIT in an answer and accept that one to show everyone that this solved your problem as it did with mine.

Comment: @Christian posted a more sustainable solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this will help other coming across this question.
As mentioned on my edit:

> After further investigation, I noticed that when an app is Freshly installed then I use pm grant every thing works as expected. However after denying the permission manually (from settings) pm grant is not working anymore

A solution (that worked for me) is to reset the permissions before trying to set them again. Call:

```
cmd appops reset my.package.app
```

Then:

```
pm grant my.package.app android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
pm grant my.package.app android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE 
pm grant my.package.app android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO 
pm grant my.package.app android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the privacy changes document for Android 10. Seams that Android stop supporting to read phone state starting with Android 10.

Copped from Android Website

> If your app targets Android 10 or higher, a SecurityException occurs.
>
> If your app targets Android 9 (API level 28) or lower, the method
> returns null or placeholder data if the app has the READ_PHONE_STATE
> permission. Otherwise, a SecurityException occurs.

Please refer bellow link for more details.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#proc-net-filesystem

Comment: I'm aware of the privacy changes, however they affect non-resettable IDs, `READ_PHONE_STATE` is necessary for other kind of operations too. Also this doesn't explain why the other permissions are not working either